# Normalization or standardization data input for SVM scikitlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm

As the subject says, I have some troubles in normalization and
standardization of the datasets for SVM regression in scikitlearn.

My questions are:

1. When I want to search the parameters for the SVM ( `C` and `gamma`
   for example) and I use this code:

   ```
   param_grid = [
     {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'kernel': ['linear']},
     {'C': [1, 10, 100, 1000], 'gamma': [0.001, 0.0001], 'kernel': ['rbf']},
    ]

   svr = svm.SVC()
   clf = grid_search.GridSearchCV(svr, param_grid)
   clf.fit(X_train,TargetT)
   ```

   Should I standardize the  `X_train` and `TargetT` vectors in the `fit` function?

   `X_train` contains values between -1 and 1 and `TargetT` is a vector of 0
   and 1 with mean not equal to 0 and `std` not equal to 1.
2. I tried to use the `preprocessing.StandardScaler()` function on
   the `InputTraining` and `InputValidation` datasets but when I check the
   values of the mean I have values for each feature not equal to 0 (the
   order is e-14) and the std is something like 1.00000985. Is that
   normal or am I doing something wrong? I wanted to use the scaled
   dataset as input for a SVM as the code belove:

   ```
   scalerI = preprocessing.StandardScaler()
   X_train = scalerI.fit_transform(InputT)
   X_test = scalerI.transform(InputCross)
   svr = SVR(kernel='rbf', epsilon=0.01, C=100, gamma = 0.01)
   y_rbf = svr.fit(X_train,TargetT)
   y_hat=svr.predict(X_test)
   ```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Only the input features `X_train` need standardization, not the target variable which is supposed to be integer values for classification tasks (e.g. an array of 0 and 1 for binary classification) or an string labels (e.g. `'spam'` vs `'ham'`). For regression tasks (predicting continuous variable like a temperatures in Celsius degrees or a price in dollars), it can sometimes help to standardize the target but this is often not as helpful as standardizing the input features.
2. 1e-14 is close enough to 0.0 and 1.00000985 is close enough to 1.0.

As a side not you can shorten your code using a pipeline:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
pipeline = make_pipeline(
    preprocessing.StandardScaler(),
    SVR(kernel='rbf', epsilon=0.01, C=100, gamma = 0.01),
)
pipeline.fit(X_train, TargetT)
y_hat = pipeline.predict(X_test)
```

To grid search the parameters of the innner models of such a pipeline you will have to use to prefix with the lowercase version of the class name: e.g. `'svr__C'`, `'svr__gamma'` and `'svr__epsilon'`.

Comment: Ok  thank you !  About the second point,  I supposed that since they were close enough to 0 and 1 they were still ok as input for the SVM but I was not totally sure. Thank you for the pipeline suggestion